Illegal instruction (core dumped) when importing tensorflow
I set up my virtual environment at remote server, and I got python=3.7, tensorflow = 2.3.0 and numpy = 1.18.5.
Everything works well until I import tensorflow.
There is a error message: Illegal instruction (core dumped).
It seems that I have to modify something in core of the remote server, but I don't have permission to do it.
Does anyone know how to solve it?
P.S I cannot downgrade my tensorflow, since the model I need run in tensorflow2.
